# Why does the output of the type-conversion from float to integer change after 15 decimal places?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(124.99999999999999) #14 Decimal Places
print(a)

#Output: 124
 
b = int(124.999999999999999) #15 Decimal Places
print(b)

#Output: 125
```

I would like to know the working behind this as the output remains `0` in the above code when `124` is replaced with `0` even with 15 decimal places of 9.

Comment: Integer conversion is a red herring. `125.0 == 124.999999999999999` and `1.0 == 0.99999999999999999`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the typing of c++ when i was working on my toy programming language project i ended up dealing with all the numbers ( int or float ) as float in c++ and since there is built in cast between float an double in c++ an most of python  interpreter have been made with c++ think that when you reach the 15 digit after the dot it is converted to double and since double is way too precise i might actually been decided by the python designer that from double to int python should be rounding to the biggest